# Packing bins equally with restricted packages

Tags: optimization

I have a problem relating to workers living in different locations visiting locations which have different rewards.  I think it is easiest to explain in terms of packing bins equally:
There are 40 bins.  We are given 200 packages of integer size between 1 and 10.  Each package can only go in certain bins (usually there are about 5 options).  We wish to pack the bins as evenly as is possible given the restrictions on where they can be placed.  By evenly I mean in a fair way – I guess a combination of making the emptiest bin as full as possible and minimising the variance.

I have not found a similar problem elsewhere so was wondering if anyone has any suggested algorithms?  I have an idea:
Take each package in descending order and put them in the emptiest available bin.  If the bins are equally packed then put the package in the bin that has the lower value of packages remaining that could go in it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I am now thinking that a better (and simpler) algorithm would be: Take each package in descending order and put them in the available bin with the lowest potential total value (which is updated after every package is assigned).

Comment: While there might be some potentially interesting statistical issues here, your mostly algorithmic question will probably fare better on StackOverflow, so you may want to ask the mods to move it over there.

Comment: This is the either the [bin packing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4825465/62576) or [knapsack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3885570/62576) problem.